# Textview Lazyloading, setText at wrong position in gridview?

Tags: android, lazy-loading

I have created a gridview, which shows videos from server. GridItem has video thumb image, and video duration.for loading video's thumb I am using UniversalImageloader and loading video duration by creating lazyloading using asynctask.Lazyloading works fine. but if someone scrolls gridview freequently,then video duration shows at wrong position. for creating Lazyloading I am following bellow [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final TextView durationTextView;

    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_roll_item, parent, false);

        MediaItemViewHolder mediaItemViewHolder = new MediaItemViewHolder();
        mediaItemViewHolder.highlightTagIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_media_grid_item_highlight_tag);
        mediaItemViewHolder.mediaTypeIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_media_grid_item_type);
        mediaItemViewHolder.mediaClipLength = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_media_grid_item_length);
        mediaItemViewHolder.mediaThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_media_grid_item_thumbnail);
        mediaItemViewHolder.cameraItemSelectedView = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_item_selection_parent);
        mediaItemViewHolder.progressContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_grid_loader_parent);
        view.setTag(mediaItemViewHolder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;//(MediaItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        //mediaItemViewHolder.mediaClipLength.setText("");
        Log.i(TAG, "set blank to ");
    }
    MediaItemViewHolder mediaItemViewHolder = (MediaItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    durationTextView = mediaItemViewHolder.mediaClipLength;
    if (position >= mCameraMediaItems.size()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Index out of Bound, position:" + position + " - mCameraMediaItems.size():" + mCameraMediaItems.size());
        return convertView;
    }
    MediaItemBean mediaItemBean = CameraMediaController.getInstance().getMediaItemByPosition(position);
    mediaItemViewHolder.mediaClipLength.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mediaItemViewHolder.highlightTagIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (mediaItemBean != null && mediaItemBean.getCameraMedia() != null) {
        switch (mediaItemBean.getCameraMedia().getType()) {
            case AppConstant.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
                mediaItemViewHolder.mediaTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icn_thumb_vid);
                //VideoInfoAsyncTask loads data in this list
                int videoDuration = mediaItemBean.getVideoDuration();
                //mediaItemViewHolder.mediaClipLength.setTag(CameraMediaUtil.convertSecondsTimeToMinutesString(videoDuration));
                Log.i(TAG, "VideoDuration " + videoDuration);

                String resId = mediaItemBean.getCreatedId()+"video_media_duration_com.gopro.buckhorn";
                Log.i(TAG, "RESID "+resId);
                downloadDuration(resId, durationTextView, mediaItemViewHolder.highlightTagIcon, mediaItemBean);
                break;
            case MULTI_PHOTO:
                String mulCount = String.valueOf(Controller.getInstance().getPhotoCountAtPosition(position));
                Log.i("MULTI_SHOT_SECTION", "MultiShot "+mulCount);
                mediaItemViewHolder.mediaTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icn_thumb_burst);
                mediaItemViewHolder.mediaClipLength.setText(mulCount);
                break;

        }
        //Load image into image view from URL
        String imageUri = mediaItemBean.getThumbnailUri().toString();
        Log.i(TAG, "Thumb url :" + imageUri);
        mediaItemViewHolder.progressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        DownloadImageUtil.getLoadImageInsatnce().downloadGridImage(imageUri,
                mediaItemViewHolder.mediaThumbnail, R.drawable.thumb_load, mediaItemViewHolder.progressContainer);
    }

    return convertView;
}


private void downloadDuration(String resId, TextView textView, ImageView highlightTagIcon, MediaItemBean mediaItemBean) {
    String duration = getVideoDurationFromCache(String.valueOf(resId));
    Log.i(TAG, "downloadDuration " + duration);
    if (duration == null) {
        loadVideoDuration(resId, textView, highlightTagIcon, mediaItemBean);
        textView.setText("");
    } else {
        cancelVideoDurationDownloaderTask(resId, textView);
        if(mediaItemBean.getCameraMedia().getType() == AppConstant.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
            textView.setText(duration);
            if (mediaItemBean.isIsHighLightTags()) {
                highlightTagIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}


private String getVideoDurationFromCache(String key) {
    // First try the hard reference cache
    synchronized (mMemoryCache) {
        final String duration = mMemoryCache.get(key);
        if (duration != null) {
            // Bitmap found in hard cache
            // Move element to first position, so that it is removed last
            mMemoryCache.remove(key);
            mMemoryCache.put(key, duration);
            return duration;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


private static class MediaItemViewHolder {
    ImageView highlightTagIcon, mediaTypeIcon, mediaThumbnail;
    TextView mediaClipLength;
    RelativeLayout cameraItemSelectedView;
    /* ProgressBar innerProgressBar;
     ProgressBar outerProgressBar;*/
    RelativeLayout progressContainer;
}

public class VideoDurationDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final WeakReference<TextView> videoDurationReference;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> hiliteTagImageViewWeakReference;
    private String data = "";
    private MediaItemBean mediaItemBean;

    public VideoDurationDownloaderTask(TextView textView, ImageView hiliteTagIcon, MediaItemBean mediaItemBean) {
        this.mediaItemBean = mediaItemBean;
        videoDurationReference = new WeakReference<>(textView);
        hiliteTagImageViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(hiliteTagIcon);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        data = params[0];
        Log.i(TAG, "data in task "+data);
        return downloadVideoDuration(mediaItemBean);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (isCancelled()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "isCancelled " + result);
            result = "";
        }
        addDurationToMemoryCache(data, result);
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (videoDurationReference != null) {
            TextView videoDuration = videoDurationReference.get();
            Log.i(TAG, "videoDuration " + videoDuration);
            VideoDurationDownloaderTask videoDurationDownloaderTask =
                    getTextViewDerationWorkerTask(videoDuration);
            Log.i(TAG, "videoDurationDownloaderTask " + videoDurationDownloaderTask);
            if (videoDuration != null) {
                if (this == videoDurationDownloaderTask) {
                    if(mediaItemBean.getCameraMedia().getType() == AppConstant.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "TAG VAL "+videoDuration.getTag());
                        videoDuration.setText(result);
                        videoDuration.setTag(new TextView(context));
                        if (mediaItemBean.isIsHighLightTags()) {
                            ImageView highlightTagIcon = hiliteTagImageViewWeakReference.get();
                            if (highlightTagIcon != null)
                                highlightTagIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private String downloadVideoDuration(MediaItemBean mediaItemBean) {
    try {
        if (media != null && mediaItemBean.getMedia() != null) {
            int videoDuration = mediaItemBean.getVideoDuration();
            Log.i(TAG, "Video has duration = " + videoDuration);
            if (videoDuration == -1) {
                CommandResult<Integer> duration =
                        media.getVideoDuration(mediaItemBean.getCameraMedia().getFilePath());
                videoDuration = duration.getData();
                mediaItemBean.setVideoDuration(videoDuration);
                Log.i(TAG, "set Video Duration " + videoDuration);
            }
            return MediaUtil.convertSecondsTimeToMinutesString(videoDuration);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception Occure while Getting video info:" + e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "not fetch duration ");
    return "";
}


public void loadVideoDuration(String resId, TextView textView, ImageView hiliteTagIcon, MediaItemBean mediaItemBean) {
    if (cancelVideoDurationDownloaderTask(resId, textView)) {
        final VideoDurationDownloaderTask task = new VideoDurationDownloaderTask(textView, hiliteTagIcon, mediaItemBean);
        AsyncTextView asyncTextView = new AsyncTextView(context, task);
        textView.setTag(asyncTextView);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}

private boolean cancelVideoDurationDownloaderTask(String data, TextView textView) {
    final VideoDurationDownloaderTask durationWorkerTask = getTextViewDerationWorkerTask(textView);

    if (durationWorkerTask != null) {
        final String textViewData = durationWorkerTask.data;
        Log.i(TAG, textViewData + " textViewDataData, data " + data);
        if (data != null && !textViewData.equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
            // Cancel previous task
            Log.i(TAG, "Cancel previous task " + data);
            durationWorkerTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            // The same work is already in progress
            Log.i(TAG, "same work is already in progress " + false);
            return false;
        }
    }
    // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was
    // cancelled
    Log.i(TAG, "cancelVideoDurationDownloaderTask true");
    return true;
}

static class AsyncTextView extends TextView {
    private final WeakReference<VideoDurationDownloaderTask> textviewWorkerTaskReference;

    public AsyncTextView(Context context, VideoDurationDownloaderTask textviewWorkerTask) {
        super(context);
        textviewWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<>(textviewWorkerTask);
    }

    public VideoDurationDownloaderTask getTextViewWorkerTask() {
        return textviewWorkerTaskReference.get();
    }
}

private static VideoDurationDownloaderTask getTextViewDerationWorkerTask(TextView textView) {
    if(textView.getTag() != null){
        Log.i(TAG, " textView.getTag() " + textView.getTag());
        if (textView.getTag() instanceof AsyncTextView) {
            Log.i(TAG, " Return Textview task");
            final AsyncTextView asyncTextView = (AsyncTextView) textView.getTag();
            return asyncTextView.getTextViewWorkerTask();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void addDurationToMemoryCache(String key, String duration) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, duration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code for GridView rendering, data binding to it and lazy loading stuff?

Comment: @AnuragSingh  can you please see the implementation?

Comment: do the below changes as answered below.

Comment: add `convertView = null`; before `if (convertView == null)..`

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of `view` and use `convertView` as you receive from method. Change to the following

```
//final is optional but if you need to use in thread
final MediaItemViewHolder mediaItemViewHolder = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_roll_item, parent, false);

    mediaItemViewHolder = new MediaItemViewHolder();
    mediaItemViewHolder.highlightTagIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_media_grid_item_highlight_tag);
    mediaItemViewHolder.mediaTypeIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_media_grid_item_type);
    mediaItemViewHolder.mediaClipLength = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_media_grid_item_length);
    mediaItemViewHolder.mediaThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_media_grid_item_thumbnail);
    mediaItemViewHolder.cameraItemSelectedView = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_item_selection_parent);
    mediaItemViewHolder.progressContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_grid_loader_parent);
    convertView.setTag(mediaItemViewHolder);
} else {
    mediaItemViewHolder = (MediaItemViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    Log.i(TAG, "set blank to ");
}
```

Now use `mediaItemViewHolder.durationTextView.setText(....)`

**Update 1:** I have figured out the problem. **Why lazyloading update video duration at wrong gridview position**. **Discard the above if you want**

```
downloadDuration(resId, durationTextView, mediaItemViewHolder.highlightTagIcon, mediaItemBean);
```

is the culprit. `downloadDuration` runs in async mode and it has the reference of `durationTextView` in before hand. Suppose the `downloadDuration` is not finished and user scrolls the `ListView`. After scrolling the `ListView` `downloadDuration` is finished, then this `durationTextView` will be updated with the value but for the wrong `ListView` item position and not for which position this was passed in `downloadDuration`. Making `final TextView durationTextView;`
 it as final will also not solve the problem.
Solution could be to show some kind of empty indicatior for duration and let the `downloadDuration` finishes it's async job. Remove `durationTextView` as a parameter and add `position` as a parameter. After async job is done, you can update the bean list of type `MediaItemBean` for that position. Now notify the adapter that some value has been changed and the `ListView` will update itself accordingly. **FYI** `RecyclerView` item update is more optimised than `ListView`.

**Update 2**: You can fetch the items in advance and just map it to bean. Only one time async will run.

**Update 3**: In the meantime you can check bean for the particular `ListView` item if it is 0 or not. If it is 0 show in the `durationTextView.setText("00:00:00")` else call `downloadDuration` and let it finish and update the duration value in bean. But still you need to `notify` for updating item.

Comment: You need to get rid of  if (position >= mCameraMediaItems.size()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Index out of Bound, position:" + position + " - mCameraMediaItems.size():" + mCameraMediaItems.size());
        return convertView;
    } also. Because if you have implemented as above then Index out of Bound, position cannot happen.

Comment: I have change as per your suggestion, But videoduration again set over photo item, I think I am some where lacking in lazyloading. And its an old code can't replace with recyclerview, I have tried by notify but its hang with 3k items in gridview.

Comment: By videoduration again set over photo item, you mean video duration shows at wrong position? Also even if you correct the lazy loading then also it will update wrong position. Check answer above.

Comment: Previously I have Implemented same way, fetch all item and store it into list but client raise a bug on that it should be lazyloading, only visible item can fetch duration like that.

Comment: Ok. Then you need to work on the Update 2 as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Can't fetch all item in advance, only visible item should be call duration API for fetching the duration similar like imageloading libraries (Glide)

Comment: I understand but still you cannot pass durationTextView as a parameter as mentioned in durationTextView

Comment: Then how Glide, UIL etc work fine? I think I am missing something

Comment: I think you didn't get to undersatnd the Update 1? In the mean time Glide or UIL will show the empty view.

Comment: Could I implement that feature?, for mean time show duration 00:00, if Yes please help me. As you have mentioned, notify after updating the bean, but it hangs the screen for 3k item.

Comment: If I'll notify grid, after every duration fetched, it would be freez.

Comment: Correct otherwise implement RecyclerView. Even then performance will be slow for the first time every item duartion is pulled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136148/discussion-between-anurag-singh-and-sandeep-tiwari).